# Problem with PHPMailer attaching file (only attaches after page refresh)

Tags: php

I have a script that generates a Certificate upon form submit, as well as sends the generated certificate to the recipients email address. When i enter the details into the HTML form, and submit the form, it fails and comes up with an error saying PHPMailer unable to access the file. But when i click on REFRESH on the browser window, **it then succeeds and sends the certificate via email..**

**My PHPMailer code is below:**

```
<?php include 'settings.php'; //include settings

//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';

 if (isset($_POST['generate'])) {
       $name = ucwords($_POST['name']);
        $customerref = ($_POST['customerref']);
        $date = ($_POST['date']);
        $customeremail = ($POST['customeremail']);
       //Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
   
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'mail.smtp2go.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'refurbsa.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'Y2F6ejMxbGFseTUw';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('info@electronic-cemetery.com', 'Electronic Cemetery');  // this is the sender's Email address
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['customeremail']);     //Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@electronic-cemetery.com', 'Electronic Cemetery');
    
    
    $mail->AddAttachment (dirname(__FILE__)."/CSD-Certificates/saved-certs/destruction-cert($customerref-$date).png");     //Adds an attachment from a path on the filesystem

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Your E-Waste Disposal Certificate';
    $mail->Body    = "Good day $name,<br><br>
Thank you very much for making use of our services. Your collection has been processed and I have attached your destruction certificate to this email.  
<br><br>
If you were happy with our service then it would be very much appreciated if you would spare a moment to give us your review <a href='https://www.facebook.com/eastcoastewaste/reviews'>HERE</a>
<br><br>
We look forward to assisting you with all your e-Waste needs in the future.
<br><br>
Wishing you a wonderful day further!
<br><br>
The Electronic Cemetery Team";
   
    $mail->send();
   
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
}
?>
```

**The HTML Form to input the data is below:**

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name Here...">
      </div>
       <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" name="weight" class="form-control" id="weight" placeholder="Enter Weight Here...">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Enter Date Here...">
      </div>
       <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <input type="email" name="customeremail" class="form-control" id="customeremail" placeholder="Enter Email Address Here...">
      </div>
       <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" name="customerref" class="form-control" id="customerref" placeholder="Enter Customer Reference Here...">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" name="generate" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Certificate and Send to Customer</button>
    </form>
```

**And finally the script to generate the certificate:**

```
     <?php 
      if (isset($_POST['generate'])) {
        $name = ($_POST['name']);
        $name_len = strlen($_POST['name']);
          $date = ($_POST['date']);
          $customeremail = ($_POST['customeremail']);
           $customerref = ($_POST['customerref']);
        $weight = ucwords($_POST['weight']);
        if ($weight) {
          $font_size_weight = 50;
        }

        if ($name == "" || $weight == "" || $date == "" || $customeremail == "" || $customerref == "") {
          echo 
          "
          <div class='alert alert-danger col-sm-6' role='alert'>
              Not all form fields have been filled in. Pleaes try again.
          </div>
          ";
        }else{
          echo 
          "
          <div class='alert alert-success col-sm-6' role='alert'>
              Congratulations! The certificate for $name has been generated and sent to $customeremail.</b>
          </div>
          ";

          //designed certificate picture
          $image = "CSD-Certificates/certi.png"; 

          $createimage = imagecreatefrompng($image);

          //this is going to be created once the generate button is clicked
          $output = "CSD-Certificates/saved-certs/destruction-cert($customerref-$date).png";

          //then we make use of the imagecolorallocate inbuilt php function which i used to set color to the text we are displaying on the image in RGB format
          $white = imagecolorallocate($createimage, 254, 254, 254);
          $black = imagecolorallocate($createimage, 0, 0, 0);

          //Then we make use of the angle since we will also make use of it when calling the imagettftext function below
          $rotation = 0;

          //we then set the x and y axis to fix the position of our text name
          $origin_x = 1600;
          $origin_y=700;

          //we then set the x and y axis to fix the position of our text weight
          $origin1_x = 2300;
          $origin1_y=900;
          
           //we then set the x and y axis to fix the position of our text date 1
          $origin2_x = 1850;
          $origin2_y=900;
          
            //we then set the x and y axis to fix the position of our text date at the bottom
          $origin3_x = 2200;
          $origin3_y=1980;
          
           //we then set the x and y axis to fix the position of our text date at the bottom
          $origin4_x = 2200;
          $origin4_y=2180;

          //we then set the differnet size range based on the lenght of the text which we have declared when we called values from the form
          if($name_len<=7){
            $font_size = 50;
            $origin_x = 1600;
          }
          elseif($name_len<=12){
            $font_size = 40;
          }
          elseif($name_len<=15){
            $font_size = 40;
          }
          elseif($name_len<=20){
             $font_size = 40;
          }
          elseif($name_len<=22){
            $font_size = 40;
          }
          elseif($name_len<=33){
            $font_size=40;
          }
          else {
            $font_size =50;
          }

          $certificate_text = $name;

          //font directory for name
          $drFont = "CSD-Certificates/TitilliumWeb-Regular.ttf";

         
          //function to display name on certificate picture
          $text1 = imagettftext($createimage, $font_size, $rotation, $origin_x, $origin_y, $white,$drFont, $certificate_text);

          //function to display weight name on certificate picture
          $text2 = imagettftext($createimage, $font_size_weight, $rotation, $origin1_x+2, $origin1_y, $white, $drFont, $weight);
          
           //function to display Date on certificate picture
          $text3 = imagettftext($createimage, $font_size, $rotation, $origin2_x, $origin2_y, $white, $drFont, $date);
          
            //function to display Date on certificate picture at the very bottom
          $text4 = imagettftext($createimage, $font_size, $rotation, $origin3_x, $origin3_y, $white, $drFont, $date);
          
            //function to display Date on certificate picture at the very bottom
          $text5 = imagettftext($createimage, $font_size, $rotation, $origin4_x, $origin4_y, $white, $drFont, $customerref);


          imagepng($createimage,$output,3);

 ?>
```

**QUESTION:**

Why does the PHPMailer only succeed with attaching the file after i have refreshed the page after it first fails?

Comment: It sounds like a race condition. Is the mailing code and the cert creating code in the same file and which code runs first? Will you please update your code so we can better understand the order in which it runs?

Comment: I think you need to add mailing sending code after generating certificate, so like:
- First generate certificate and add send email code after it.

Comment: yeah i figired that before reading your comments. Thanks guys. PHPmailer was going first before the cert was generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out,

All i had to do was move the PHPMailer script **BELOW** the scrip that generates and saves the certificate and it worked. So obviously i was calling the mail function before the certificate was saved. so PHPMailer wasn't able to find the file.